# jquery priority interacting with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have dynamically created input elements, I would like to do something with JQuery when I click on it. At the moment I have an Ajax connection triggered when I click on input element to retrieve some content from the server. the point is that .click() works only on the second click on the element whereas I would like to fire JQuery and not only Ajax at first click too.

inside my PHP code I have the input elements created and showNews Ajax function called:

```
<input id="ac-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="accordion-1" type="radio">
<label  for="ac-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onClick="showNews(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></label>
```

And with JQuery I would like able to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").click(function(){
    // Doing something here
  });
});
```

Now it's working at second mouse click. Could you have a look [here.](http://incubadora.massimodifa.com.br/GreatAndGatsbyDev/news/)

click() func works only at second click. I need two handled actions on the same element and on the same time.

Comment: Works fine on first click for me.

Answer (score 1):

More exact answer could be

```
$('input').focus(function(){
   // doing your thing here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $('input').focus() instead:
http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you share the code that didn't work?

Comment: I use Chrome and the code is that I wrote above. Is the click() func that works only at second click. I need two handled action on the same element and on the same time.